# Flutter GridView bottom items are cut off when nested in a Stack with an Align

Tags: flutter, gridview

My app has a `GridView` displaying a list of items. At the bottom of the `GridView` is an `Align` to filter the items. Both are the children of a `Stack`. The issue is the `Align` widget is drawn over the `GridView` widget, and cuts off the image and text of the bottommost items.

Solutions I've tried:

1. Iterate the various `clipBehavior` options of the `Stack`.
2. Wrap the `Stack` in a `Container` with `height: double.maxFinite`.
3. Temporarily remove the `Align` to see it was the issue.
4. Wrap the `Align` in `Positioned.fill`

[image: screenshot of overlay]

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget> [
      buildGridViewWidget(context, snapshot),
      buildFilterWidget()
    ]
);

GridView buildGridViewWidget(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<FoodMenuItem>> snapshot) {
  return GridView.count(
      childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
          (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.15),
      mainAxisSpacing: 6,
      crossAxisSpacing: 6,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length, (index) {
        return MenuItemWidget(snapshot.data![index]);
      })
  );
}

  Align buildFilterWidget() {
    return Align(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            buildExpandedFilterOption('all', FilterState.all),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            buildExpandedFilterOption('burger', FilterState.hamburger),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            buildExpandedFilterOption('fry', FilterState.fry),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            buildExpandedFilterOption('shake', FilterState.shake),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stack` should be replaced with a `Column` since overlapping was undesirable.

```
                Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(child: buildGridViewWidget(context, snapshot)),
                      buildFilterWidget()
                    ]
                );
```